# Avoid appending commas in jquery easyui combobox

Tags: php, jquery-easyui

I have problem in combobox of jquery easyui. I have to Avoid appending commas in jquery easyui combobox of easyui.
Please give me any solution for stop the append the comma in combobox in property multiple:true,

Thanks!

MY CODE IS:

```
 <input class="easyui-combobox"
                    name="Output"
                    id = 'cc'
                   data-options="
                    url:'data/urine_output.json',
                    valueField:'text',
                    textField:'text',
                    multiple:true,
                    selected:true,
                    panelHeight:'auto'
                    ">
```

Comment: It might help if you show us the code which is appending commas, or an illustration of the issue... or both.

Comment: <input class="easyui-combobox"
                        name="Output"
                        id = 'cc'
                       data-options="
                        url:'data/urine_output.json',
                        valueField:'text',
                        textField:'text',
                        multiple:true,
                        selected:true,
                        panelHeight:'auto'
                        ">

Comment: Er, OK. What's the content of `data/urine output.json` (delightful filename notwithstanding)?

Comment: [{
 "id":1,
 "text":"Distension"
},{
 "id":2,
 "text":"Frequent"
},{
 "id":3,
 "text":"Frequent at night",
 "selected":true
},{
 "id":4,
 "text":"Frequent day time"
},{
 "id":5,
 "text":"Not Frequent"
},{
 "id":6,
 "text":"Retentation"
},{
 "id":7,
 "text":"Satisfactory"
},{
 "id":8,
 "text":"Unsatisfactory"
}]

Comment: I'm not sure I can, with the information I have. Can you edit the question to perhaps include a screenshot of your result, as well as the JS with which you set up the combobox on your element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is a bit late for you, but I answer anyway because this point is not documented in the official easyui documentation.
You just have to add the '**separator**' property :

```
data-options="      url:'data/urine_output.json',
                    valueField:'text',
                    textField:'text',
                    multiple:true,
                    selected:true,
                    panelHeight:'auto',
                    separator:'|'     
                    "
```